# Need Inline ManytoMany Field add in django admin

Tags: python, django

I am creating a manytomany field in my model and creating a Inline Tabular with though also. but on django admin it is showing dropdown. and if I add new then it shows a Popup. But I dont want Popup. Instead of that I want inline add as in case of Foreign Key.
Thanks in advance. Please help...

```
class ExamInline(admin.TabularInline):
    # classes = ['collapse']
    model = Form.exam.through
    extra = 0
```